# Fast multiplication/summation of mathematical series in python

Tags: python, math

I am working on a (scientific) code where the following product is calculated repeatedly (for many different values of `ni`):

```
ll = np.arange(m);
x = np.prod(1. - ni / (n - ll))
```

where `n` is always greater than `m+ni`.

Typical values of `m` are tens of milions or greater and teh calculation is somewhat slow. How could I accelerate it? (E.g., using iterators or itertools or functools)?

More generally, provided that I have mathematical series, dependent on index (i.e., function fo an integer number `f(i)`), what is the fastest way to calculate sums or producs of many members of these series? Can it be done without first creating a list and then using `np.sum` / `np.prod`,

```
np.sum([f(i) for i in range(i)])
```

?

**Supporting information:** the typical mathematical for of interest is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4252758/765359).

Comment: "Can it be done without first creating a list" - you can use generators: `sum(f(i) for i in range(i))` or even `sum(map(f, range(i)))`

Comment: In general, iterators will be much slower than vectorized numpy functions. With so many factors, precision can also cause serious problems.

Comment: @JohanC even if operating on vectors with ten of millions components?

Comment: @RogerVadim Take a look at [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/).

Comment: @RogerVadim  Especially with tens of millions of elements.  Numba might be a good alternative.  If `ni`  is often smaller than `m`, some factors will cancel out.  Note that your formula looks a lot like combinatorics formulas, for which there exist fast approximations.

Comment: @JohanC indeed, it could be written in terms of factorials, but numpy doesn't handle well such big numbers

Comment: My advice is to try to simplify it via algebraic manipulations and then implement the resulting formula. In that context it might help to restate it in terms of factorials (with the goal of getting to a non-factorial result). It might also help to take the logarithm and work with the resulting summation. I remember log(1 + x) is approximately x for x near 0, maybe that's relevant. If `ni/(n - l1)` isn't close to 0 for some range of values, maybe sum those directly, and then work algebraically on the tail of small values.

Comment: I work with Maxima (https://maxima.sourceforge.io) for that kind of stuff, but you can also try Sympy (https://sympy.org) or SageMath, whatever works for you.